# Access locally deployed Servicefabric micro service from another machine on same/different network

Tags: networking, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have service fabric based microservice deployed locally on my test machine.

I would like to access the service endpoint from another machine.

Example: Once I deploy service fabric locally I use something like
http://lastname.com:47830/v1/api/endpoint.

How would I reach to this endpoint from another machine, considering authorizations are figured out.

Comment: Wouldn't just using http://{ip-of-host}:47830/v1/api/endpoint work? If not what happens?

Comment: would this be public ip of host? I got it from https://www.whatismypublicip.com/ and it did not work. If I just provide the ip address how would it understand which service to go to?

Comment: Does it need to be reachable from the outside? I was assuming you want to communicatie it using a machine on the same network, is that assumption correct? If so the local ip of the target machine should be useable. And any firewall on the target machine must allow traffic to port 47830.

Comment: That work by allowing traffic to port. Thats the piece I was missing. Thanks. This ended up being a networking question.

Comment: Hello @user2934433, Could you please post the solution as answer so that it helps others?

Answer (score 0):

Target machine must allow traffic to port 47830. Then  http://{ip-of-host}:47830/v1/api/endpoint  works